# Appending a token list keeps referring to it instead of copying

Tags: expl3, latex3, xparse, key-value

I actually had some workarounds and overcame my issue. But I still cannot understand some points.

I'm trying to write a command to draw a table. I started with this:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_contact_tl
\newcommand \AddContact[2]{
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_contact_tl {#1}
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_contact_tl {&#2}
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_contact_tl {\\}
}
\NewDocumentCommand \PrintContact {}{
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
        \tl_use:N \l_contact_tl
    \end{tabular}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\AddContact{ABC}{123}
\AddContact{\href{tel:+01 123-456-789}{+01 123-456-789}}{\raisebox{0.5pt}{\scalebox{0.75}{\faEnvelope}}}
\PrintContact

\end{document}
```

It works perfectly:

[image: No key-value]

But when I try key-value command:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_contact_tl
\keys_define:nn {contact}{
    ,info .tl_set:N = \l__contact_info_tl
    ,icon .tl_set:N = \l__contact_icon_tl
}
\NewDocumentCommand \AddContact {m}{
    \keys_set:nn {contact}{#1}
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_contact_tl {\l__contact_info_tl}
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_contact_tl {& \l__contact_icon_tl}
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_contact_tl {\\}
}
\NewDocumentCommand \PrintContact {}{
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
        \tl_use:N \l_contact_tl
    \end{tabular}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\AddContact{
    info={ABC},
    icon={123}
}
\AddContact{
    info={\href{tel:+01 123-456-789}{+01 123-456-789}},
    icon={\raisebox{0.5pt}{\scalebox{0.75}{\faEnvelope}}}
}
\PrintContact

\end{document}
```

The last record will overwrite all above one:

[image: key-value]

When I change to specifier `x`, it works with normal text without `\href` and `\fontawesome`:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand \AddContact {m}{
    \keys_set:nn {contact}{#1}
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_contact_tl {\l__contact_info_tl}
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_contact_tl {& \l__contact_icon_tl}
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_contact_tl {\\}
}
...
\AddContact{
    info={ABC},
    icon={123}
}
\AddContact{
    info={XYZ},
    icon={456}
}
\PrintContact

\end{document}
```

[image: Normal text with x specifier]

If I send an icon, a `raisebox`, an `scalebox` or `href`, it gives back some types of error.

Finally, I figure out this work but still can't understand why:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand \AddContact {m}{
    \keys_set:nn {contact}{#1}
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_contact_tl {\unexpanded\expandafter{\l__contact_info_tl}}
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_contact_tl {& \unexpanded\expandafter{\l__contact_icon_tl}}
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_contact_tl {\\}
}
```

I think I misunderstand some key points about token expansion here.
Does anyone have an idea about this? Thank you.

Comment: you want No not Nn or nV to access the value of the variable

Answer (score 4):

## Some explanations

When you do `\tl_put_right:Nn` the second argument will be stored as is inside in your token list (no expansion whatsoever takes place). When you store a macro (or another token list) inside of your first token list this way it would just contain the macro, and when you eventually use the first token list the inner one will expand to the replacement it has by that point.

So what you're doing in plain TeX syntax would be:

```
\def\foo{A}
\def\bar{\foo}
\def\foo{B}
```

and upon using this `\bar` will expand to `\foo` which will expand to `B`.

As you correctly realised you'll need to expand your inner token list. When you use an `x`-argument in `expl3` syntax that means "fully expand as far as possible", but some macros (many, especially the older ones) aren't save in such a context. So when you run that on arbitrary content you never know whether this works out.

You then used `\unexpanded\expandafter{<stuff>}`. That will be the same as "expand once" (which is `o` in `expl3` syntax). That's because `\unexpanded` expands all tokens until it finds an opening brace, so expands `\expandafter` which will expand the first token in `<stuff>` before `\unexpanded` then finds the opening brace and protects everything in that group from further expanding (removing the braces). In `expl3` language the function doing the same is `\exp_not:o`. So instead of what you did you could've used

```
\tl_put_right:Nx \l_contact_tl
  {
    \exp_not:o { \l__contact_info_tl & }
    \exp_not:o { \l__contact_icon_tl \\ }
  }
```

---

## Some code

Instead of using `x`-type expansion you could just expand the internal token lists once, using `\tl_put_right:No` instead:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_contact_tl
\keys_define:nn {contact}{
    ,info .tl_set:N = \l__contact_info_tl
    ,icon .tl_set:N = \l__contact_icon_tl
}
\NewDocumentCommand \AddContact {m}{
    \keys_set:nn {contact}{#1}
    \tl_put_right:No \l_contact_tl {\l__contact_info_tl&}
    \tl_put_right:No \l_contact_tl {\l__contact_icon_tl}
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_contact_tl {\\}
}
\NewDocumentCommand \PrintContact {}{
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
        \tl_use:N \l_contact_tl
    \end{tabular}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\AddContact{
    info={ABC},
    icon={123}
}
\AddContact{
    info={\href{tel:+01 123-456-789}{+01 123-456-789}},
    icon={\raisebox{0.5pt}{\scalebox{0.75}{\faEnvelope}}}
}
\PrintContact

\end{document}
```

But I'd suggest small adjustments: Make the token list you build global and put your key=value parsing in a group, this way the different calls to `\AddContact` can't interfere with each other (for instance if you don't specify an icon for one contact it would use the previously used icon with the local implementation):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g_contact_tl
\keys_define:nn {contact}{
    ,info .tl_set:N = \l__contact_info_tl
    ,icon .tl_set:N = \l__contact_icon_tl
}
\NewDocumentCommand \AddContact {m}{
  \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn {contact}{#1}
    \tl_gput_right:No \g_contact_tl {\l__contact_info_tl&}
    \tl_gput_right:No \g_contact_tl {\l__contact_icon_tl}
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_contact_tl {\\}
  \group_end:
}
\NewDocumentCommand \PrintContact {}{
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
        \tl_use:N \g_contact_tl
    \end{tabular}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\AddContact{
    info={ABC},
    icon={123}
}
\AddContact{
    info={\href{tel:+01 123-456-789}{+01 123-456-789}},
    icon={\raisebox{0.5pt}{\scalebox{0.75}{\faEnvelope}}}
}
\AddContact{
    info=Stuff,
    % no icon
}
\PrintContact

\end{document}
```

An alternative to grouping and using a global list would be to use `\tl_clear:N \l__contact_info_tl \tl_clear:N \l__contact_icon_tl` before `\keys_parse:nn`.

[image]

Comment: You come to rescue again. It's amazing that it can be solved with a small tweak. Thank you for the very detailed and intelligible answer, but I still can't understand why putting the `&`  with the second token list can't make it work. Can you put some explanation or refer to some documents?

Comment: @thanhph111 Because `\tl_put_right:No` will expand the *first* token. If you put `&` in front of `\l__contact_icon_tl` you don't expand that once, but try to expand `&`. But `&` isn't expandable and nothing happens.

Answer (score 4):

You want to add the *value* stored in the token list. So you want

```
\tl_put_right:NV \l__thanhph_contact_tl \l__thanhph_contact_info_tl
```

and not `\tl_put_right:Nn`.

I'd also add the `&` separately, because it doesn't really belong to either operation.

You also need to clear the variables, or you'd end up with the previous values if `info` or `icon` are not stated in an `\AddContact` command.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% user interface
\NewDocumentCommand \AddContact {m}
  {
   \thanhph_contact_add:n { #1 }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \PrintContact {}
  {
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
      \tl_use:N \l_thanhph_contact_tl
    \end{tabular}
  }

% variables
\tl_new:N \l_thanhph_contact_tl
\keys_define:nn {thanhph/contact}
  {
    info .tl_set:N = \l__thanhph_contact_info_tl ,
    icon .tl_set:N = \l__thanhph_contact_icon_tl ,
  }

% internal code
\cs_new_protected:Nn \thanhph_contact_add:n
  {
    \keys_set:nn {thanhph/contact}{info=,icon=,#1}
    \tl_put_right:NV \l_thanhph_contact_tl \l__thanhph_contact_info_tl
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_thanhph_contact_tl { & }
    \tl_put_right:NV \l_thanhph_contact_tl \l__thanhph_contact_icon_tl
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_thanhph_contact_tl { \\ }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\AddContact{
    info={ABC},
    icon={123}
}
\AddContact{
    info={\href{tel:+01 123-456-789}{+01 123-456-789}},
    icon={\raisebox{0.5pt}{\scalebox{0.75}{\faEnvelope}}}
}
\PrintContact

\end{document}
```

Note that the proper naming scheme requires something more; I used your name as the first part, then `contact` as the module name. This will reduce chances of conflict with other people's code.

You might add everything in a single step:

```
\tl_put_right:Nx \l_thanhph_contact_tl
  {
    \exp_not:V \l__thanhph_contact_info_tl
    &
    \exp_not:V \l__thanhph_contact_icon_tl
    \exp_not:N \\
  }
```

but this requires more control over expansion. With `\exp_not:V`, the value is used, but not further expanded.

[image]

Actually, I'd recommend this approach if you need to apply formatting to the items. Here I make the info into boldface, but do nothing (this is easily changeable with the helper function) to the icon.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% user interface
\NewDocumentCommand \AddContact {m}
  {
   \thanhph_contact_add:n { #1 }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \PrintContact {}
  {
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
      \tl_use:N \l_thanhph_contact_tl
    \end{tabular}
  }

% variables
\tl_new:N \l_thanhph_contact_tl
\keys_define:nn {thanhph/contact}
  {
    info .tl_set:N = \l__thanhph_contact_info_tl ,
    icon .tl_set:N = \l__thanhph_contact_icon_tl ,
  }

% internal code
\cs_new_protected:Nn \thanhph_contact_add:n
  {
    \keys_set:nn {thanhph/contact}{info=,icon=,#1}
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_thanhph_contact_tl
     {
      \__thanhph_contact_format_info:n { \exp_not:V \l__thanhph_contact_info_tl }
      &
      \__thanhph_contact_format_icon:n { \exp_not:V \l__thanhph_contact_icon_tl }
      \exp_not:N \\
     }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__thanhph_contact_format_info:n { \textbf{#1} }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__thanhph_contact_format_icon:n { #1 } % do nothing special

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\AddContact{
    info={ABC},
    icon={123}
}
\AddContact{
    info={\href{tel:+01 123-456-789}{+01 123-456-789}},
    icon={\raisebox{0.5pt}{\scalebox{0.75}{\faEnvelope}}}
}
\PrintContact

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your explanation clears my confusion, but I wonder is it better to wrap the code with `\group_begin:`, `\group_end:` and use `\tl_gput_right` to avoid reusing old token, like the [answer of Skillmon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/625920/255698)?

Comment: And if I want to pass my `\l__thanhph_contact_info_tl` or `\l__thanhph_contact_icon_tl` to a function before appending, e.g. `\textbf` or `\textcolor`, how can I achieve that? They seems to be broken with `{`.

Comment: @thanhph111 you could use `\tl_put_right:Nx \l_thanhph_contact_tl { \exp_not:N \textbf { \exp_not:V \l__thanhph_contact_info_tl } }`.

Comment: @thanhph111 No need to use grouping; as you see, before evaluating the keys, I clear them. For the formatting, see the edit.